# The class does not exist in Laravel script reset user's password

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use from "reset the password" option in my laravel script, but when I enter the email address in the password reset form and send the reset request, it will display the Error:

> Class App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\FrontendController does not exist

The FrontendController:

```
class Frontendcontroller extends Controller
    {
        public function index(){
           $services = OurService::inRandomOrder()->take(4)->get();
           $testimonials = Testimonial::all();
           $faqs = Faq::all();
           $customers = User::count();
           $subscribers = Subscriber::count();
           $orders = Order::count();
           return view('frontend.index', compact( 'services', 'testimonials', 'faqs', 'customers', 'subscribers', 'orders'));
        }

        public function forgotPass(Request $request)
        {
            $this->validate($request,
                [
                    'email' => 'required',
                ]);
            $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

            if ($user == null) {
                return back()->with('alert', 'Invalid Email Address');
            } else {
                $to = $user->email;
                $name = $user->name;
                $subject = 'Password Reset';
                $code = str_random(30);
                $message = 'Use This Link to Reset Password: ' . url('/') . '/reset/' . $code;

                PasswordReset::create(
                    ['email' => $to, 'token' => $code]
                );

                send_email($to, $name, $subject, $message);

                return redirect()->route('login')->with('success', 'Password Reset Email Sent Succesfully');
            }

        }

        public function resetLink($code)
        {
            $reset = PasswordReset::where('token', $code)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
            if (is_null($reset)) {
                return redirect()->route('login')->with('alert', 'Invalid Reset Link');
            } else {
                if ($reset->status == 1 || Carbon::now() > $reset->created_at->addHour(1)) {
                    return redirect()->route('login')->with('alert', 'Invalid Reset Link');
                } else {
                    return view('auth.passwords.reset', compact('reset'));
                }
            }
        }

        public function passwordReset(Request $request)
        {
            $this->validate($request,
                [
                    'token' => 'required',
                    'password' => 'required|min:6',
                    'password_confirmation' => 'required|min:6',
                ]);
            $reset = PasswordReset::where('token', $request->token)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
            $user = User::where('email', $reset->email)->first();
            if ($reset->status == 1) {
                return redirect()->route('login')->with('alert', 'Invalid Reset Link');
            } else {
                if ($request->password == $request->password_confirmation) {
                    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
                    $user->save();
                    PasswordReset::where('email', $user->email)->where('token', $request->token)->update(['status' => 1]);

                    $msg = 'Your Password has been Changed Successfully';
                    send_email($user->email, $user->username, 'Password Changed', $msg);
                    return redirect()->route('login')->with('success', 'Password Changed Successfully');
                } else {
                    return back()->with('alert', 'Password Not Matched');
                }
            }
        }

        public function subscription(Request $request)
        {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:subscribers',
            ],
                [
                    'email.unique' => 'You are already subscribed into our site',
                ]);
            $excep = $request->except('_token');
            Subscriber::create($excep);
            $status = 0;
            return $status;
        }

        public function announcement(){
            $items = Announcements::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
            return view('frontend.announcement', compact('items'));
        }

        public function announcementDetails($id){
            $item = Announcements::findOrFail($id);
            return view('frontend.announcementDetails', compact('item'));
        }

        public function contact(Request $request){
            $email = GeneralSetting::first();
            $msg = 'Email from ' . $request->name . '<br/> Email: ' . $request->email . '<br/> Phone: ' . $request->phone . '<br/> Subject: ' . $request->subject . '<br/> Message: ' . $request->message;
            send_email($email->e_sender, 'Contact Email', $request->subject, $msg);
            session()->flash('success', 'Message Sent Successfully');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
```

How I must do?
Other send email options are working, for example the system of email verification is working well, but reset password not work :(

Comment: Are u sure you have set your namespace? i doesnot see it between your codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller name is `Frontendcontroller`, but you used it as `FrontendController`. (C not 'c')

Answer (score 0):

Please update your class name and also file name

**Class Name**

```
class Frontendcontroller extends Controller
```

To

```
class FrontendController extends Controller
```

**File Name**

`Frontendcontroller.php` **To** `FrontendController.php`